# Qt: connect() requires at least 4 arguments, but 2 were provided

Tags: c++, qt, connect

What am I missing here, why is the following example giving me compile-time errors?

testline.h:

```
#include <QLineEdit>
class TestLine : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestLine(QWidget *parent = 0);
public slots:
    virtual void on_textEdited(const QString&);
};
```

testline.cpp:

```
#include "testline.h"
TestLine::TestLine(QWidget *parent) : QLineEdit(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &))), this,
            SLOT(on_textEdited(const QString &)));
}

void TestLine::on_textEdited(const QString &text)
{
   // something
}
```

error message:

```
../testline.cpp:7:5: error

: no matching member function for call to 'connect'
    connect(this, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &))), this,
    ^~~~~~~
../../../Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qobject.h:219:43: note: candidate function template not viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 2 were provided
```

Comment: `SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &)))` one too many close parentesis.

Comment: You have one too many )

Comment: Better double check those parentheses...

Comment: Since you are using Qt 5 (5.7 from your output), start using the [new connect syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), it would have potentially solved the problem since you do not have all the braces:  `connect(this, &TestLine::textEdited, this, &TestLine::on_textEdited);`

Comment: If you use Qt 4's `connect` syntax (why?) you should prefer the normalized signatures. In your case, `SIGNAL(textEdited(QString))`. The topmost references and consts should be removed, and all unnecessary spaces must be removed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(textEdited(const QString &)))
//     1            2          3               321
```

At this point you are doing what exactly the compiler output says - you are calling `connect()` with only 2 parameters.